# How To Force Insert In CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.9

I have a MySQL archive table with the following structure:

```
    `histories` 
      `uid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `param` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `param2` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `time` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
     ENGINE=ARCHIVE DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I do **not** want to add an auto-incrementing `id' column. This table's engine is archive and it does exactly what I need it to, with this structure.

I wish to save like this:

```
$this->History->create();
$this->History->save(['uid' => uid, 'type' => 'deleted_entry', 'param' => $thing_id]);
```

But CakePHP forces an update, which I don't want and the ARCHIVE engine doesn't support. Cake seems to be looking for a primary key of uid, finding it and deciding that it should update and there seems to be no flag available to force an insert. I do not want to resort to `$this->Model->query()`.

**UPDATE:**
Set `$primaryKey = null` in AppModel. `$this->create();` will then insert.

```
class History extends AppModel {
    public $primaryKey = null;
}
```

**If you want to do an update after, simply:**

`$this->History->primaryKey = 'uid';` before the `save()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell Cake 2 that you have no primary key by setting the model's `$primaryKey` property to `null`:

```
$this->History->primaryKey = null;
$this->History->create();
$this->History->save(['uid' => uid, 'type' => 'deleted_entry', 'param' => $thing_id]);
```

Comment: That's a user ID, not an auto-increment ID. I need to specify the user ID because the log pertains to a user.

Comment: I misunderstood the meaning of `uid` in the question, so I've updated the answer.

Comment: So, neither of those methods worked, but you gave me an idea: to set the $primaryKey = null in the model. That worked! (with just create()) Thanks :}

Comment: Great, I'm glad I at least got you in the right direction. I will update the answer with your information for future users :)